# Flipping a signal

Tags: voltage, amplifier, level-shifting

I've an input of two input lines, one being connected to ground and one carrying the signal (measured to ground). The output should be three lines with one being ground and the others measured in respect to ground. There should be two possible uses:

1. Input is 0V output should be -0.4V and 0.4V
2. Input is 5V output should be 0.4V and -0.4V

An output current of just 10-15 µA is enough. Input can be up to 40mA (however if needed, supply voltage outside these ranges can be supplied). Can you please give me any hints?

Comment: Huh?  What is "0.4V/-0.4V/0V"?  You question makes no sense in its current form.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I hope I made my question clearer.

Comment: You have edited your question in a different way than the comment to my answer; please double check it. :) And try to insert a figure if possible.

Comment: @clabacchio: The third line is just ground (0V). I'm not sure where's the difference? I try to make a figure in a moment.

Comment: I think you are asking how to convert a single-ended input (0-5V) into a differential output with 1.6 V differential range and 0 V common mode voltage. I don't have time to give you a complete circuit, but that description gives you some terms to search for. A "differential op-amp" like TI's THS4502, with an appropriate feedback circuit, should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Your answer is still unclear as to what that 0 .. 5V input is: analog, or maybe digital? For the analog case you seem to need a divider, level shifter, and inverter. For the analog case an analog multiplexer with the suitable inputs delivered by resistor dividers might be an eassier solution.

Comment: @Herbert, is the input analog or digital? What is the highest frequency involved? What is the lowest frequency involved -- does the response have to go down to DC or is the input always switching? What power supply voltages do you have available?

Comment: @ThePhoton: There is a 15V power supply and the input is digital, just the two cases, so there is DC output involved, only switching. Frequency is fairly low, at most it is changing maybe every few seconds and I don't mind if it takes a few fractions of a second.

Comment: @Herbert, in that case things are more difficult because you need to produce -0.4 V output but you only have a positive supply. If your signal was switching more often you could achieve this with ac-coupling but at the rate you mention, that's not a good option either. Most likely you will need to add a negative supply or use a switching regulator circuit to generate a negative supply.

Comment: @TheProton: As the currents are very low, can't I just use, maybe an `ICL7660` or similar?

Comment: @Herbert, Looks like it should work, but I'm not personally familiar with that part.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what means 0.4V/-0.4V/0V, but if you mean a signal of amplitude 0.4V and centered on 0, you need an amplifier and level shifter, or simply an amplifier with common mode rejection.

You could use an operational amplifier in non-inverting mode, with gain 0.8/5 = 0.16, using as a reference voltage at the inverting pin 2.5V instead of ground. To create the 2.5V reference, you can use a voltage divider with two equal resistors.

EDIT: the idea of the voltage divider was wrong, as you will have a current flowing in it that will unbalance the value. You can use a differential amplifier configuration such as [this](http://www.simplecircuitdiagram.com/2010/03/24/op-amp-application-level-shifting-amplifier/)

UPDATE: So you have two output signals, that fortunately are one the opposite of the other. So you will need only an inverter (amplifier with gain -1) to generate the second from the first.

Now, considering the first, you  have to generate 0.4V when the input is 5V, and -0.4V when the input ois 0V. That brings us to my previous answer.

OR, as The Photon said, you can use a differential-in differential-out amplifier.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was not clear: I mean I have to input lines, with one being ground (0V) and one being the signal (5V measured to ground). I need an output of three lines: ground, 0.4V measured to ground and -0.4V measured to ground. Hope that makes my question clearer.

Comment: @Herbert no it's less clear if possible :) You need that 5 becomes 0.4, 0 becomes -0.4 and 2.5 becomes 0 right?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that. There are two possible cases: 1) Input is 0V/0V then output should be -0.4V/0.4V/0V 2) Input is 5V/0V then output should be 0.4V/-0.4V/0V My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a diagram of how this can be done with a differential op-amp:

[image: single-ended to differential circuit]

In the diagram I show LT1994 as the amp because it was convenient to test in LTSpice, but something like TI's THS4504 would probably work equally well.

I used a Shottky diode to limit the input voltage to the op-amp circuit on the assumption that it's forward voltage would be more stable than the high voltage of the 5 V input signal. If you trust the input voltage to be consistently 5.0 V (or whatever) you could just use a resistor divider instead of the diode limiter. If you need extreme precision in getting the output amplitude to exactly +/- 0.4 V you could substitute a precision active limiter circuit in place of the Shottky diode.

I haven't checked the phase margin of this circuit. Then amp is advertised as unity gain stable, but its probably worth double-checking.

Here's the output for a slow 5 V square wave input:
[image: output waveform]