# Symmetric voltage oscillator

Tags: oscillator, differential-amplifier

How do I create an oscillating output (around 50 to 80 MHz) with both negative and positive voltage (parallel)?

I have got already a 48 MHz oscillator, but I don't mind about replacing it if it's required.

[image]

Comment: What do you need it for? (e.g. what's it driving, etc)

Comment: Huh? "Parallel" is not a meaningful attribute of voltage.

Comment: That is what you would call a double-ended differential signal.

Comment: @Kortuk: So he wants two signals, one inverted from the other? "Differential pair" would have been a good name, or possibly "symmetric" with a little explanation. I can understand some people may not be good with english, but then they should go to extra lengths to make sure they are clear, certainly not pick unusual words out of the air without additional explanation and expect others to know what they mean. I would have answered this long ago if it had been more clear.  In any case this was a drive-by question.  He hasn't been back since that day.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I was actually commenting to the poster as to what the signal is called, it was not directed at you. On that note, it is still valuable for those that look this up in the future, remember, helping the OP is only the source, the goal is to create a repository of knowledge. Also, you are very experienced but I still clearly remember the days where being told that I had a double-ended differential signal would not make sense to me. Looking this up when you really have no idea what it is called is a more daunting task then you might realize.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to get such "inverted" clock signals is to get a "differential" oscillator that has both "CLK+" and "CLK-" output (clock and complementary clock), such as the
50 MHz Silicon Labs [530EB50M0000DG](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Silicon-Laboratories/530EB50M0000DG/?qs=wPAQMce%252b0%252bnY0pNCGEVRQg==), the Cypress [CY24293](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=422&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=CY24293&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial) (requires an external 25 MHz crystal to generate up to 100 MHz), etc.

If you already have a single-ended clock signal, you could generate clock and complementary clock output signals using a variety of IC with differential outputs, such as the ON Semiconductor MC100LVEL16, the Fairchild Semiconductor FIN1108MTD, etc.

Then, if necessary, you could use a DC blocking capacitor and a resistor (or diode) to level-shift (DC restoration) the signals where you want them, and perhaps a resistor divider to get the peak-to-peak levels you want.

It's possible to build a [50 MHz oscillator out of common parts](http://emcesd.com/50mhzosc.htm) based on a 74HC240 inverter, but it requires a bunch of tuning and tweaking.

At lower frequencies, I would generate the appropriate frequency, and then use an inverter to generated the complementary signal -- however, at 50 MHz, the inverter delays are a significant fraction of the complete cycle, so I'd prefer to use an IC with differential outputs so they're both delayed the same amount.
Out of curiosity, what sort of device are you feeding this kind of positive and negative complementary clock into?

Comment: An inverter with a delay the same as his period may work

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is a normal oscillator feeded into a differential amplifier, such as the one posted [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25955/flipping-a-signal)

But you need a device with a good bandwith, at least 50-80 MV/s of slew rate, and also in that case you would obtain a triangular wave; so you need to fit that spec according to the steepness required for the edges.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However I've not found an amplifier with such high bandwith (40 MHz was already labelled as exceptionally high). Do you know any other alternative?

Comment: @Pat Do you already have an oscillating signal at that frequency?

Comment: I've an oscillator with 48MHz (would be enough), I don't mind however if it is replaced.

Comment: @Pat there could be a discrete solution, but at that speed I think that it should be done at a small scale, maybe integrated scale; I'll try to look if there is anything suitable, otherwise I'll not be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the required phase accuracy and output impedance, the simplest approach may be to run the signal through an inverter.  If you're using +5 logic levels, scale the positive-phase output to 0.5 volts by feeding it into a resistor divider with a 9:1 resistance ratio (e.g. 9K and 1K).  To get the negative-phase output, if a -0.5V supply is available, use a 9.5K resistor to the inverter output and a 1K resistor to -0.5V.  If -0.5 is not available but some more-negative supply is, use three resistors--one to the negative supply, one to ground, and one to the inverter output.